# Liquid Area issue with Greensock & Gaia

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, gaia

I have a flash file that I'm trying to change backgrounds for each page. The background itself changes nicely but I'm having a problem getting the background to scale to the stage size. I'm using Greensock's Liquid Area to try and handle it and it does well with a single background but as soon as I introduced more my code choked..

```
package com.picturesite.pages
{
    import com.gaiaframework.api.*;
    import com.gaiaframework.debug.*;
    import com.gaiaframework.events.*;
    import com.gaiaframework.templates.AbstractPage;
    import com.greensock.TweenMax;
    import com.greensock.easing.*;
    import com.greensock.layout.*;

    import flash.display.*;
    import flash.events.*;

    public class IndexPage extends AbstractPage
    {   
        public var bg1:MovieClip;
        public var bg2:MovieClip;
        public var bg3:MovieClip;
        public var bg4:MovieClip;
        public var bg5:MovieClip;
        public var bg6:MovieClip;
        public var newBG:MovieClip;
        public var bBar_mc:MovieClip;   


        var releaseGaia:Function = Gaia.api.afterTransitionOut(onAfterTransitionOut, true);

        public function IndexPage()
        {
            super();
            alpha = 0;

        }
        override public function transitionIn():void 
        {
            super.transitionIn();
            bg2.visible=bg3.visible=bg4.visible=bg5.visible=bg6.visible=false;
            TweenMax.to(this, 0.3, {alpha:1, onComplete:transitionInComplete});     

            var ls:LiquidStage = new LiquidStage(this.stage, 960, 760, 960, 760);
            var area:LiquidArea = new LiquidArea(this, 0, 0, 960, 760);
            area.attach(newBG, ScaleMode.PROPORTIONAL_OUTSIDE);
            ls.update();
        }

        override public function transitionOut():void 
        {
            super.transitionOut();
            TweenMax.to(this, 0.3, {alpha:0, onComplete:transitionOutComplete});
            Gaia.api.removeAfterTransitionOut(onAfterTransitionOut);
        }

        private function onAfterTransitionOut(e:GaiaEvent):void
        {
            var newBG:MovieClip;

            switch(Gaia.api.getCurrentBranch())
            {
                case Pages.HOME :
                    newBG = bg1;
                    break;

                case Pages.PACKAGES :
                    newBG = bg2;
                    break;

                case Pages.PHOTOS_SAMPLES :
                    newBG = bg3;
                    break;

                case Pages.VIDEOS_SAMPLES :
                    newBG = bg4;
                    break;

                case Pages.TESTIMONIES :
                    newBG = bg5;
                    break;

                case Pages.CONTACT :
                    newBG = bg6;
                    break;

            }

            TweenMax.allTo([bg1,bg2,bg3,bg4,bg5,bg6], .5, {autoAlpha:0});
            TweenMax.to(newBG, .5, {alpha:1, onComplete:releaseGaia});  

        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not really sure about the thing, but this line:

```
TweenMax.to(this, 0.3, {alpha:0, onComplete:transitionOutComplete});
```

maybe fades out everything. If I saw it well on the library's homepage, that code hides everything, because the code sets *alpha* to *0* in *0.3* secs. Is that right? If so, then maybe change `this` to `newBG`, if you want to fade the `newBG` object out. So far it seems you fade out the whole thing.

So:

```
TweenMax.to(newBG, 0.3, {alpha:0, onComplete:transitionOutComplete});
```

Or in `onAfterTransitionOut`, put

```
this.alpha = 1;
```

Hope this helps or gives you some idea.

Comment: I will try a longer time but the problem is not the alpha value but that they do no scale to the full stage size in "transitionIn"... yes everything fades because the only thing in this file is the backgrounds.